# How do I turn multiple while loops into a function that runs through an object?

Tags: javascript

I've got to create random x y positions for 4 weapons in a turn based board game. At the moment I've got 4 separate while loops doing this successfully; how can I simplify this and create a function that runs through the values of an object creating the positions? Thanks.

```
    var GameObjects={
  Weapon1:4,
  Weapon2:5,
  Weapon3:6,
  Weapon4:7,
}

  this.size=10;
  map=[];

// create weapon locations
var i=0;
while (i<1) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  if (map[x][y]== GameObjects.Grass){
    map[x][y]=GameObjects.Weapon1;
    i++;
  }
}

var i=0;
while (i<1) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  if (map[x][y]== GameObjects.Grass){
    map[x][y]=GameObjects.Weapon2;
    i++;
  }
}

var i=0;
while (i<1) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  if (map[x][y]== GameObjects.Grass){
    map[x][y]=GameObjects.Weapon3;
    i++;
  }
}

var i=0;
while (i<1) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*map.length);
  if (map[x][y]== GameObjects.Grass){
    map[x][y]=GameObjects.Weapon4;
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// A small helper to generate random integers in [0, range[
const rand = range =>    Math.floor(Math.random() * range);

function placeRandomly(el, on){
   let x, y;
   // search a random location with "on"
   do {
     x = rand(map.length);
     y = rand(map.length);
   } while(map[x][y] !== on)
   // Then replace it with el
   map[x][y] = el;
 }
```

Now you can simply do:

```
placeRandomly(GameObjects.Weapon1, GameObjects.Grass)
```